# having trouble passing args from java to groovy script

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to write a cucumber test (using cucumber-jvm) to run a groovy script on a sample file and verify that the data is properly stored in a db. (I did not write the groovy script, which runs just fine from the command line).  I can't seem to get the args into the groovy script properly.  Can anyone tell me how to get this to work?

The groovy script has the following code:

```
/** Check command line options.  */
def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'groovy scriptname.groovy [-h] -f file')
cli.h(longOpt: 'help', 'Usage information', required: false)
cli.f(longOpt: 'file', 'File with information', args: 1)

OptionAccessor opt = cli.parse(args)
if(!opt) {
  return
}
else if(opt.h || !opt.f) {
  cli.usage()
  return
}
/** Process file.  */
def file = new File(opt.f)
```

My java code contains the following:

```
final GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
final Binding binding = new Binding();
final String[] args = {"-f", fileFn};
binding.setVariable("args", args);
final File file = new File(scriptFn);
final Script script = shell.parse(file);
script.run();
```

The groovy script works just fine when run from the command line.  When I run
it from the java/cucumber step definition, I get the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: args for class: FWLoader
at FWLoader.run(FWLoader.groovy:171)
```

The line in the groovy script that is failing is

```
OptionAccessor opt = cli.parse(args)
```

Any suggestions? I am new to groovy and fairly new to java (many years programming in C/C++ though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's maybe a typo, but you are missing a `script.setBinding(binding)` :

```
final Script script = shell.parse(file);
script.setBinding(binding); // <-- here
script.run();
```

Comment: that did it... I've been googling a lot on this subject and somehow missed that requirement.